# Settings Sync prompts for login every time VSCode restarts

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I open/restart vscode, it asks me to sign in to sync settings. I've tried running `code --disable-extensions` but it still asks me to sign in to sync settings. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this [over here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/224#issuecomment-383324321). Basically, I needed to install `gnome-keyring` and `libsecret`.

Comment: Will it fix the problem on MacOS as well?